# Publishing release notes to TFS/VSTS Wiki during Release

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, azure-pipelines, wiki, release-notes

My mission is to generate and publish release notes on WIKI automatically when ever the release triggered, for this I am following this [Blog](https://scatteredcode.net/publishing-release-notes-to-tfs-vsts-wiki-during-release/), its very handy blog, but my bad luck still not able to create wiki page with release template. (using both Azure DevOps and TFS)

[image]

**Template:**

```
**Build Number**  : $($build.buildnumber)    
**Build started** : $("{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}" -f [datetime]$build.startTime)     
**Source Branch** : $($build.sourceBranch)  
###Associated work items  
@@WILOOP@@  
* #$($widetail.id)
@@WILOOP@@  
###Associated change sets/commits  
@@CSLOOP@@  
* **ID $($csdetail.changesetid)$($csdetail.commitid)** 
  >$($csdetail.comment)    
@@CSLOOP@@
```

**PowerShell Script**

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\releasenotes.md")
$data = @{content=$content;} | ConvertTo-Json;
$params = @{uri = '$(WikiPath)';
  Method = 'PUT';
  Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" };
  ContentType = "application/json";
  Body = $data;
}
Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, we find that the PowerShell script in your mentioned [blog](https://scatteredcode.net/publishing-release-notes-to-tfs-vsts-wiki-during-release/) uses this Rest API: [Pages - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create%20or%20update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), thus the wikipath is the requested url like below format:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path={path}&api-version=6.0`

For example, we create a project wiki named **scrum-test.wiki**, and want to create a new wiki page named **Release notes**, the url would like below

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/scrum-test.wiki/pages?path=Release notes&api-version=6.0`

If we now want to create a child wiki page named 0.1.0 under Release notes page, the url would be like below

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/scrum-test.wiki/pages?path=Release notes/0.1.0&api-version=6.0`

In addition, using AccessToken we always get error which says that `"The wiki page operation failed with message : User does not have write permissions for this wiki."` even we grant full wiki permissions for identity: **{project name} Build Service ({organization name})**, so we use [PAT authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) with full access and it works fine with below PowerShell script.

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\releasenotes.md")
$data = @{content=$content;} | ConvertTo-Json;

$connectionToken="PAT here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$params = @{uri = '$(WikiPath)';
  Method = 'PUT';
  Headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" };
  ContentType = "application/json";
  Body = $data;
}
Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

Comment: Thanks all, $(WikiPath) was the problem, corrected the link and now able to create the wikis pages as expected,

Answer (score 1):

Check access to `System.AccessToken` on the job level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

[image]

Additionally, check permissions on your wiki

[image]

Comment: Nice catch, now my log shows Status Code:200 and Status Description: OK, but still WIKI page is not created :( would you please share me the value of $(WikiPath) consumed in PS script

Comment: @SaadAwan, I did not use this extension and can just suggest some ideas )). Check permissions of build services on the wiki security.